# How to use the EventLogEntryCollection class to parse event logs

Tags: c#, parsing, event-log

I am trying to make an event log parser, I am currently testing out the method of putting the event log into a EventLogEntryCollection, so I can easily get the number of event log entries and easily get individual ones from the collection, but when I attempted it I royally screwed it up. How would I fix this and if I can't what is a better way of going about doing this.

The errors themselves just seem to be that it doesn't think anything I made below exists it says "The name of "etc." does not exist in the current context".

```
    public static class EventLogEntryCollection_Container
    {
        public static void testCollection()
            {
                string myLogName = "_log";

                // Create an EventLog instance and assign its source.
                public static EventLog _log = new EventLog();
                _log.Source = "%Program Files (x86)%\\EventLogParser\\ImportedEventLogs\\" + varBank.logInput;

                // Write an informational entry to the event log.
                _log.WriteEntry("Successfully created a new Entry in the Log");
                _log.Close();

                // Create a new EventLog object.
                EventLog myEventLog1 = new EventLog();
                myEventLog1.Log = myLogName;

                // Obtain the Log Entries of "_log".
                EventLogEntryCollection _logCollection = _log.Entries;
                _log.Close();

                // Copy the EventLog entries to Array of type EventLogEntry.
                EventLogEntry[] _logEntryArray = new EventLogEntry[_logCollection.Count];
                _logCollection.CopyTo(_logEntryArray, 0);
                IEnumerator myEnumerator = _logEntryArray.GetEnumerator();
                while (myEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    EventLogEntry myEventLogEntry = (EventLogEntry)myEnumerator.Current;
                }
            }
    }
```

> End goal is to be able to put the parse event logs into a table like
>   layout in a windows forms project.

Comment: Why is there `public static` inside testCollection? Are you trying to declare a field or a local variable?

Comment: To be perfectly honest I was just hacking away to see if I could get the errors to disappear, it got a few of them to go away, but nothing significant, when I first wrote it didn't have public static.

Comment: You either need to remove `public static` to make `_log` a local variable or move its declaration outside of the method to make it a field.

Comment: That makes the errors go away, but now I can't access any of that data, so I can put it in windows forms